# What does "gin-and-water reporter" mean?

Tags: meaning

The term is from "The Difference Engine" by Bruce Sterling and describes a certain kind of journalist. The story is set at the time of Charles Babbage and Ada Lovelace/Byron.

What does it mean?

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant, but I'll include the quote: "Mallory, having met more that his share of gin-and-water reporters, hacks pursuing wide-eyed articles on the great Leviathan, registered a faint twinge of anxiety; this fellow evinced the smooth self-possession of the extremely well-advantaged.

Comment: I think that gin and water was the drink of the poor (I recall it in _Oliver Twist_. This is contrasted with the "extremely well-advantaged".

Comment: The phrase occurs 11 times in _Oliver Twist_: one is the dying midwife, three are Fagin's gang, and the rest are all Mr Bumble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps if you read the before and after.

> Mallory, having met more than his share of gin-and-water reporters,
>   hacks pursuing wide-eyed articles on the great Leviathan[...]

In short: Hack reporters. It is considered a sin amongst the gin aficionados to mix gin and water.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Turns out I did not know the proper meaning of hack-journalist (I'm German), but Wikipedia explains it nicely: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hack_writer

Answer (score 0):

This is inference, from the words as well as the excerpt, as I could not find a source to support this directly.

Gin = Clear, 
Water = Clear

Someone who offers you one thing and surreptitiously provides another for their own benefit.